# Converting all word document in a folder to txt using python

Tags: python, ms-word

I am trying to convert word document to txt. Changing the extension doesn't work. I need to open it in word ,then save it to .txt format
I am using code from here http://code.activestate.com/recipes/279003-converting-word-documents-to-text/

```
import fnmatch, os, pythoncom, sys, win32com.client

wordapp = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")

try:
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
        for doc in [os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path, filename)) for filename in files if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '*.doc')]:
            print "processing %s" % doc
            wordapp.Documents.Open(doc)
            docastxt = doc.rstrip('doc') + 'txt'
            wordapp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(docastxt, FileFormat=win32com.client.constants.wdFormatTextLineBreaks)
            wordapp.ActiveWindow.Close()
finally:
    wordapp.Quit()
```

however when I run it the first file will work perfectly but giving error on the second file

here are the error msg

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "recipe-279003-1.py", line 11, in <module>
    wordapp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(docastxt, FileFormat=win32com.client.constants.wdFormatTextLineBreaks)
  File "C:\Users\moxzhang\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 474, in __getattr__
    return self._ApplyTypes_(*args)
  File "C:\Users\moxzhang\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 467, in _ApplyTypes_
    self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args),
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147023179, 'The interface is unknown.', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "recipe-279003-1.py", line 14, in <module>
    wordapp.Quit()
  File "C:\Users\moxzhang\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.7\00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x8x7\_Application.py", line 353, in Quit
    , OriginalFormat, RouteDocument)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147023179, 'The interface is unknown.', None, None)
```

I have tried only put one word file in the directory , it works fine. but once i have 2 files there. the procedure will fail on the 2ed file (both file will convert succesfully if it is the only file in the folder)

Could you please let me know what this error message means ? and what can I do to fix it.

Comment: posted the code , thanks

Comment: This is just a guess, from reading your code. You're closing the window, not the document. That will leave the first document open, which may mean it remains the "ActiveDocument". If this were VBA I'd be sure you should: use a variable for the `Document` object, assigning it during the Open method. Something like `wordDoc = wordapp.Documents.Open(doc)` then `wordDoc.SaveAs(...)` and `wordDoc.Close`.